# object slick is not a member of package scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to import scala.slick in my play project but I keep getting "object slick is not a member of package scala error"

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

I'm using scala 2.11.6, play 2.4.x

Answer (score 6):

I found out that I have to use

```
import slick
```

instead of

```
import scala.slick
```

Comment: The `scala.slick` package was moved to `slick` between versions 2 and 3. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html